# Making my dice throws produce more throws?

Tags: c#

I'm working on an assignment, where I have to make an application where you can throw 1-4 dice. The results are then added to a list.
**However**, if any of them is a **6**, that one *isn't* added to the list, instead **2 additional dice are thrown**.

As long as a die returns a **6**, 2 more dice have to be thrown, until no die returns a 6.

Does anyone here know how to solve this? My programming skills are really basic, and I haven't used them much since last year.

```
for (int i = 0; i < qty; i++)
{
  int diceNr = RollDice(random);
  dicelist.Add(diceNr);
  Console.WriteLine(diceNr);
  if (diceNr == 6)
{
dicelist.Remove(diceNr);
Console.WriteLine("You got a six, that means you get 2 extra throws!");

   for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
   {
       diceNr = RollDice(random);
       dicelist.Add(diceNr);
   }
```

Comment: You may want to lean about "recursive", since your assignment indicates "throw 2 more dices until no die returns a 6." @C.Evenhuis's solution is another good approch.

Comment: I would have an integer `throwsRemaining` variable, and use a `while (throwsRemaining > 0)` loop instead of a regular `for` loop - then decrement or increment `throwsRemaining` depending on the thrown dice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`while` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while) that exits once you are out of rolls. If you roll a six, add two more to the remaining quantity otherwise add the rolled value to the list.

```
int qty = 6;

// decrement remaining quantity each iteration 
// until zero rolls remain
while(qty-- > 0)
{
   int diceNr = RollDice(random);

   Console.WriteLine(diceNr);

   if (diceNr == 6) 
   {
      // rolled six, add two more rolls
      Console.WriteLine("You got a six, that means you get 2 extra throws!");
      qty += 2; 
   } 
   else 
   {
      // not six, add to list
      dicelist.Add(diceNr); 
   } 
}

// output all the non-six values 
var allRolls = string.Join(",", diceList);
Console.WriteLine("All rolls: " + allRolls);
```

You *could* also do this with [recursion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29?wprov=sfla1) (though I don't recommend it for this problem):

```
private static void Play(List<int> diceList, Random random, int rolls)
{
   // base case, no rolls remain 
   if (rolls == 0) 
      return;

   int diceNr = RollDice(random);
   Console.WriteLine(diceNr);

   if (diceNr == 6)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("You got a six, that means you get 2 extra throws!");
      // add one to rolls since we are "reusing" this slot 
      // adding two would give us one more roll than we really want
      rolls++
   } 
   else 
   {
      diceList.Add(diceNr);
      // decrement rolls by one
      rolls--;
   }
   // recursively call Play with updated roll count
   // which is either original + 1 OR original - 1
   Play(diceList, random, rolls);
} 

private static int RollDice(Random r)
{
    return r.Next(1, 7);
} 

public static void Main()
{
   var diceList = new List<int>();
   var random = new Random();
   int qty = 6;

   Play(diceList, random, qty);

   // output all the non-six values 
   var allRolls = string.Join(",", diceList);
   Console.WriteLine("All rolls: " + allRolls);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `while` loop as follows:

```
int i = quantity; #initialize a variable to your maximum number of throws
while(i > 0){ #until you have throws yet
    i--; #this is the equivalent of one throw
    int diceNr = RollDice(random);
    dicelist.Add(diceNr);
    Console.WriteLine(diceNr);
    if(diceNr == 6){
        Console.WriteLine("You got a six, that means you get 2 extra throws!");
        i = i + 2; #add your bonus throws
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed it as well, if it's six it shouldn't be added to the list

Answer (score 0):

My (readable) solution would look like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var game = new Game(4);
        game.Play();
    }
}

public class Game
{
    private readonly int _noOfDices;
    private readonly List<int> _result;
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    public Game(int noOfDices)
    {
        _noOfDices = noOfDices;
        _result = new List<int>();
    }


    public void RollDice()
    {
        var no = _random.Next(1, 7);

        if (no == 6)
        {
            RollDice();
            RollDice();
        }
        else
        {
            _result.Add(no);
        }
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= _noOfDices; i++)
        {
            RollDice();
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Output: {string.Join(',',_result)}");
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: A. Recursion is unnecessary B. You're use of `new Random()` is extremely incorrect

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks for your hint. Maybe the Recursion is unnecessary, but readable. Please point out why/what is incorrect with `new Random()`